# Radio button change event not firing when radio is selected programmatically

Tags: jquery

In the following code, clicking the `selectRadio2` button does not fire the radio change event! Why not? Is there a workaround?

HTML:

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="One"/>
<label for="radio1">One</label><br/>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="Two"/>
<label for="radio2">Two</label><br/>
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="Three"/>
<label for="radio3">Three</label>

<br/><br/>
<button id="selectradio2">Select Radio 2</button>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name=radioGroup][type=radio]").change(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id") + " checked");
});

$("#selectradio2").click(function() {
    $("#radio2").prop('checked',true);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzny/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the change event requires an actual browser event initiated by the user instead of via javascript code. You need to trigger the `change` event using:

```
$("#selectradio2").click(function() {
    $("#radio2").prop('checked',true).change(); // or trigger('change')
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzny/1/)**

Comment: Fantastic! Your answer came within 26s of my question! Thanks!

Comment: And what about click event with trigger is in first js file and change event is other js file (in correct order)? Is some way to work it?

Comment: Never thought about it, you made my day. Thanks.